# sequences don't behave as excpected in general Topological spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

mas everyone.
I was wondering today, the deeper reason why sequences don't behave as we would expect in general topological spaces. We have some basic examples with cofinite topology over $ \mathbb{N}$ and others in co-countable topology over an uncountable set $ X $. after that my books states that, the  main problem for these "strange" behaviors is focused on the fact that it's possible that in a Topological space doesn't exist a countable neighborhood basis of a point $x$. ( i'm still a bit confused about the deeper connection of a basis and a neighborhood basis, as i know that they are connected, but its not on the point of the question)

Comment: When you have a countable neighborhood basis by picking a points in each you can produce a sequence with the point as limit. Sequences are enough to witness what being close to a point is in such topological space. But in other spaces a sequences might not be enough.

Comment: I picture the case of failure in two intuitive ways (that can happen also simultaneously): (1) the system of neighborhoods is too deep for a sequence. This happens, for example with the neighborhoods of $\omega_1$ in the [extended long ray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology)) Neighborhoods can shrink there more than countably many times. (2) The system of neighborhoods can be too wobbly. That happens, for example in a non-separable Hilbert space. There are many dimensions along which a neighborhood can be 'long' while small in the others.

Comment: thanks both of you. Especially @MoonLightSyzygy , can you give , if its easy to you a bit more details in the second example? I found both examples really well put, but i'll need some time to grasp the whole image of them both..( I haven't faced the idea of long line topology before..)

Comment: Ah, no. My second example is not what I wanted. Hilbert spaces are normed and then have countable neighborhood bases for each point. That example is of not-second countable. A good example for (2) is the topology of countable complements in an uncountable space. It has many big neighborhoods of a point that can leave out any sequence.

Comment: A space being first countable allows you to define open and closed sets in terms of sequences.